# Versioning of rows in database oracle in application on spring+jpa?

Tags: spring, oracle, jpa

There is application on spring+jpa+oracle.

Needs to store history of rows and versions.
1) by rest I need to get last n rows with there version number.
2) There is no delete or update operations - only write\readFresh\getAllFromHistory

Which way to implement is the best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends but the thing I'd suggest you is to utilize one of more of the features/annotations such as:

1. `@Version` for the auto-incrementing feature/property to know how many times a version has changed,
2. `@CreationTimestamp` for a property that is signifying the date an object/entry was made
3. `@UpdateTimestamp` for a property that signifies the date when an entry was last updated

A good way to implement i.e. versioning for all your entities is via utilization of `@MappedSuperclass` in an AbstractJpa class, i.e.:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractJpa {

    // some code
    private Long version;

    // getters and setters
    @Version
    @Column(name = "version_number")
    public Long getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(Long version) {
        this.version = version;
    }
}
```

Then you inherit/extend it in your other entities, i.e.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_entity")
public class MyEntity extends AbstractJpa {
    // some code, properties, getters/setters ...
}
```

---

**IMPORTANT NOTICE:**
**If you intend to save all previous entries** then it's logical to conclude that you're generally going to have the "soft delete" implementation of some sort as well. I.e. you intend to have some `is_deleted` boolean value in your database and your `@MappedSuperclass` may also have such column/property defined as well. At that same time, you should utilize insert option for each intended "update", i.e. you're going to insert new rows (`persist(myObject)`) each time you issue an update instead of performing a `merge(myObject)`.

It all depends on your specific scenario and use case, but these would be some general things to look for on the internet, I hope that helps.

Comment: except that `CreationTimestamp` and `UpdateTimestamp` are not part of JPA. Perhaps you should mention that they are specific to some particular JPA provider? (and the OP doesnt specify which one they are using, so you cant really do that if they are not using the same one as you)